# Is it possible to set own openstreetmap server url for AGSOpenStreetMapLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, arcgis

I need to represent a tiled layer with own openstreetmap server - is it possible?

Comment: It looks like the answer is no, at least using the class in the SDK https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_open_street_map_layer.html There are people that have written their own layer class on top of the SDK. I'm looking for something similar and haven't found one yet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, there is a solution in ArcGIS SDK to display non-ArcGIS map tiles as a layer to a map - `AGSWebTiledLayer`, it's init method:

```
- (id) initWithTemplateURL: (NSString *) templateURL
                  tileInfo: (AGSTileInfo *) tileInfo
          spatialReference: (AGSSpatialReference *) sr
                fullExtent: (AGSEnvelope *) fullExtent
                subdomains: (NSArray *) subdomains
```

where we can set a template url in format:

```
http://{subDomain}.host.com/{level}/{col}/{row}.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your tile server supports.
It probably support WMS, which you can consume via [AGSWMSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_w_m_s_layer.html)

Take care of specifying the visibleLayers array.